# Passing class between functions

Tags: python, scrapy

I am building a simple(ish) parser in Scrapy and I am blissfully ignorant when it comes to scrapy and Python :-) In the file `item.py` I have a definition of `thisItem()` which I assign to `item` in the code below. All worked rather swimmingly, `parse`using a callback to get to `parse_dir_content`... But then I realized I needed to scrape an extra bit of data and created another function `parse_other_content`. How do I get what is already in `item` into `parse_other_content`?

```
import scrapy
from this-site.items import *
import re
import json

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = "ABB"
     allowed_domains = ["this-site.com.au"]
     start_urls = [
        "https://www.this-site.com.au?page=1",
        "https://www.this-site.com.au?page=2",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//h3/a/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]'):
            item = thisItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            item['rate'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="rate"]/div/span/text()').extract()
            so = re.search( r'\d+', response.url)
            propID = so.group()
            item['propid'] = propID
            item['link'] = response.url
            yield scrapy.Request("https://www.this-site.com.au/something?listing_id="+propID,callback=self.parse_other_content)
            #yield item

    def parse_other_content(self, reponse):
            sel = json.loads(reponse.body)
            item['rate_detail'] = sel["this"][0]["that"]
            yield item
```

I know I am missing something simple here, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you simply want to send `item` to another method, like as a function parameter, or make it a variable visible to the entire `DmozSpider` class?

Comment: Method 1 has my preference, method 2 would work as well I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the scrapy documentation (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments):

> In some cases you may be interested in passing arguments to those callback functions so you can receive the arguments later, in the second callback. You can use the Request.meta attribute for that.

In your case I would do something like this:

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]'):
        item = thisItem()
        ...
        request = scrapy.Request("https://www.this-site.com.au/something?listing_id="+propID,callback=self.parse_other_content)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

def parse_other_content(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    # do something with the item
    return item
```

According to Steve (see comments) you can also pass a dictionary of `meta` data as a keyword argument to the `Request` constructor like so:

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]'):
        item = thisItem()
        ...
        request = scrapy.Request("https://www.this-site.com.au/something?listing_id="+propID,callback=self.parse_other_content, meta={'item':item})
        yield request
```

Comment: By what mechanism is the stuff that was already inside `item` made available to `parse_other_content`? That answer doesn't seem complete... But like I said I am blissfully ignorant when it comes to Python, so feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: The mechanism is built in to Scrapy.  The authors allow you to store data in the `request.meta` dictionary and the library is built to pass the data along to the next callback function.

Comment: Cool, but then shouldn't it be explictely passed in here: `request = scrapy.Request("https://www.this-site.com.au/something?listing_id="+propID,callback=self.parse_other_content)` as a 3rd argument perhaps?

Comment: @mcjoejoe0911 Ah. I see. I am not entirely familiar with Scrapy.

Comment: @Jeroen, not according to the documentation.  It explicitly directs using the `request.meta` as the means of passing data to another callback function.

Comment: @mcjoejoe0911 "Not according to the documentation" LOL, so you never actually tried it yourself?

Comment: @GalenNare neither am I, but a quick search of the documentation shows how to do it correctly!

Comment: @Jeroen I don't need to.  The documentation tells me that's how it should be done.

Comment: I've always put the meta inside the Request as a parameter and that definitely works. 
`yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {'ProductCode':row['ProductCode'], 'MPN': row['MPN'], 'ModuleCode' : row['ModuleCode']})`

Comment: The funny thing is, I had already poured over the part of the documentation this answer is describing, somehow it just didn't click. Thanks @mcjoejoe0911

Answer (score 0):

You can either allow `item` to be visible to `parse_other_content()` by changing it to `self.item`, or sending it as a parameter to the function. (The first one might be easier.)

For the first solution just add `self.` to any reference to the item variable. This makes it visible to the entire class.

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]'):
        self.item = thisItem()
        self.item['title'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        self.item['rate'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="rate"]/div/span/text()').extract()
        so = re.search( r'\d+', response.url)
        propID = so.group()
        self.item['propid'] = propID
        self.item['link'] = response.url
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.this-site.com.au/something?listing_id="+propID,callback=self.parse_other_content)
        #yield item

def parse_other_content(self, reponse):
        sel = json.loads(reponse.body)
        self.item['rate_detail'] = sel["this"][0]["that"]
        yield self.item
```

Comment: I would not recommend this.  Scrapy has the ability to pass items to callbacks.  See my answer.

Comment: @mcjoejoe0911 is right, don't do this. Scrapy is asynchronous, there's no guarantee that the data in self.item relates to the data being parsed in a second method. You have to pass it via `response.meta`.